# How to read latest file from a directory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can able to get latest file file info properties

```
 var Filepath  =    directory.GetFiles("myPattern").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

HttpPostedFile myFile = Filepath  ;

How to read the content of this file ?
Error: Cannnot convert file info to file
The Below is class file with properties i am trying to assign the latest file to below class file.
HttpPostedFile myFile = Fileupload1.postedfile ; // not throwing error
HttpPostedFile myFile = Filepath  ; // throwing error
Error: Cannnot convert file info to file

```
public sealed class HttpPostedFile 
{ 
// Summary: 
// Gets the size of an uploaded file, in bytes. 
// 
// Returns: 
// The file length, in bytes. 
public int ContentLength { get; } 
// 
// Summary: 
// Gets the MIME content type of a file sent by a client. 
// 
// Returns: 
// The MIME content type of the uploaded file. 
public string ContentType { get; } 
// 
// Summary: 
// Gets the fully qualified name of the file on the client. 
// 
// Returns: 
// The name of the client's file, including the directory path. 
public string FileName { get; } 
// 
// Summary: 
// Gets a System.IO.Stream object that points to an uploaded file to prepare 
// for reading the contents of the file. 
// 
// Returns: 
// A System.IO.Stream pointing to a file. 
public Stream InputStream { get; } 

// Summary: 
// Saves the contents of an uploaded file. 
// 
// Parameters: 
// filename: 
// The name of the saved file. 
// 
// Exceptions: 
// System.Web.HttpException: 
// The System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection.RequireRootedSaveAsPath property 
// of the System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection object is set to true, 
// but filename is not an absolute path. 
public void SaveAs(string filename); 
}
```

Comment: What did you try, in order to read the contents of this file?

Comment: You need to provide more code. Where does it go wrong? What are you trying to do at that exact moment?

Comment: this should not have error, unless you use the `FileContent` somewhere else or explicitly declare it with wrong type (not use `var`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're reading text file

```
  String text = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetFiles("myPattern").OrderByDescending(f => File.GetLastAccessTime(f)).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and a file's content. You can access the file's content for instance through a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by using the [`FileInfo.OpenText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var fileInfo = directory.GetFiles("myPattern")
                        .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                        .First();
using (StreamReader sr = fileInfo.OpenText()) {
    String s = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: @wudzik nope, it should be static `Directory` method which returns array

Comment: OpenRead() method is not in the current context

Comment: @Arya Modified my answer, now using `OpenText()` instead of `OpenRead()`

Answer (score 0):

`Filepath` is `FileInfo` object you can't set that to a `HttpPostedFile`

```
FileInfo file =    directory.GetFiles("myPattern").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
if (file != null)
   string contents = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
```

Answer (score -1):

**I got the required soluction by following code :**

> var myFile=Directory.GetFiles(".").OrderByDescending(f =>
>   f).FirstOrDefault();